# Steam friends went offline

Tags: steam

My Steam friends went offline today for no good reason. I understand the server goes down sometimes but usually it auto reconnects as soon as the server is up again but this time it was different.

This was the exact message:

> you are currently set to appear offline to all your friends.

I had to reconnect manually by pressing go online button which is pretty weird. It just went offline automatically and didn't reconnect.

What could be the reason for that?

Comment: It must be Hackers!!!

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, Steam only makes an attempt to reconnect every few minutes so it doesn't overwhelm the same servers that have just been offline (perhaps due to overloading!).

By clicking on that button, you forced Steam to attempt a reconnection; it just so happened that that one attempt worked. :)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, when the servers go down steam actually says so and there is no reconnect button available :) I have a feeling it might have been something else since go online button was available. It's like I set the offline mode myself except that I didn't. Or maybe I'm just being paranoid :)